# How to stack only some of pandas DataFrame series on bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a following DataFrame:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plotdata = pd.DataFrame({
    "pies_2018":[40, 12, 10, 26, 36],
    "pies_2019":[19, 8, 30, 21, 38],
    "pies_2020":[10, 10, 42, 17, 37],
    "pies_produced": [100, 80, 75, 10, 60]
    }, 
    index=["Dad", "Mam", "Bro", "Sis", "Me"]
)
plotdata.plot(kind="bar")

plt.title("Mince Pie Consumption Study Results")
plt.xlabel("Family Member")
plt.ylabel("Pies Consumed")
```

Now I'm looking for a way to plot a stacked bar chart, but I would like to stack only some series (*pies_20**), and *pies_produced* should be presented next to stacked series, to show how consumed pies are compared to pies produced. So in the end I should get two bars for each family member. I don't want to sum *pies_* *, because I still want to distinguish between consumption in time. See drawn example for *Bro*.

Would it be possible to show a legend with value for every year next to the stacked bar?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to plot twice with option `stacked` and `position`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

# plot first 3 columns, stacked and shifted left
plotdata.iloc[:,:-1].plot.bar(stacked=True, position=1, width=.4, ax=ax)

# plot last column, shifted right
plotdata.iloc[:,-1:].plot.bar(position=0,color='C4', width=.4, ax=ax)

ax.set_xlim(-0.5, len(plotdata)-0.5)
```

Output:

[image]